# Math - how to calculate arccos formula?

Tags: math, formula, trigonometry

can anyone help me to calculate Arccos(X) ? with some formula ? 
I'm trying to do it in some environment (SAP WEBI) with limited math formulas. ( have only cos , sin , tan.. ).

Comment: Ok, from your other comment I see you don't have `atan` - what accuracy do you need? If you don't need it exactly, you can prebuild a table of cosines and look-up nearest value to get the inverse. Otherwise you might be stuck with an integral or infinite series [as described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions).

Comment: I need to calculate the distance between to points ( latitude/longtitude) , I've found this formula : (ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-X1)) *COS(RADIANS(90-X2)) +SIN(RADIANS(90-X1)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-X2)) *COS(RADIANS(Y1-Y2))) *6371)*1000
but I can't calculate ACOS in my system (WEBI). do you have any suggest? thank you. Mor

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27943/2065121) is related and has an alternative but still needs at least `atan` :-(

Comment: It might be better to [ask this question on Math](http://math.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In WEBI there isn't way to calculate ACOS so there is 2 solutions:

> 

1) create a new custom function in c++ and import it to WEBI

> 

2) create a universe and use ACOS there.

Mor

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Newton's method:

```
function acos(a) {
    delta = 1e-5
    // a lousy first approximation
    x = pi*(1-a)/2
    last = x
    x += (cos x-a)/sin x
    while ( abs(x-last) > delta ) {
        last = x
        x += (cos x-a)/sin x
    }
    return x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions :

```
# for -1 < x <= +1 :
acos(x) == 2*atan( sqrt(1-x*x)/(1+x) )
```